# how to Get the CRUD Level Access logs for Azure Files

Tags: azure, azure-files

how to Get the CRUD Level Access logs for Azure Files , if any one has used it to check on who has accessed the file , any update they did or deleted the file on Azure Files . Please let me know if you can help

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Azure Storage has Diagnostic settings that can write the logs about the Blob, Queue, and Table, except the File. You can the Diagnostic settings in the storage account like this:

[image]

When you set the logging, it will write the logs and store them in the storage account. For example, when you set the logging, you can see the logs like this:

[image]

That is what I know to write the logs about CRUD level. But only the File does not have the feature. Not pretty sure if there is another way to achieve what you want, but most likely there is no another way.